# gentoo connect to external mysql

Tags: mysql, gentoo

how can help me to connect to external mysql?

system: 
cat /etc/gentoo-release
Gentoo Base System release 2.3

```
mysql -h vpsxxx.ovh.net --port=12000 -u userxxx -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1042 (HY000): Can't get hostname for your address

mysql -h 149.xxx.xx.xx --port=12000 -u userxxx -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1042 (HY000): Can't get hostname for your address
```

From another system with windows and Debian working this adress perfekt.

Comment: This is a DNS failure, that hostname doesn't exist. Maybe it's only published internally on OVH because it's a reserved address like 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x where you simply *cannot* connect externally.

Comment: no its a externl ip adress and vps. over the ip/vps can i see my website. And from windows and debian can i connect to the mysql server. only from gentoo working noting!

Comment: This is not a programming issue for Stack Overflow. Check your DNS settings.